# Permission of .bundle/config for Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, rubygems, passenger, redmine

Have searched but couldn't seem to find this exact question. Am installing Redmine 3.2.1 on my Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS server with Apache 2.4.18 and Passenger 5.1.1. I keep getting this error:

```
There was an error accessing `/usr/share/redmine/.bundle/config`.
The underlying system error is Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory @ io_fread - /usr/share/redmine/.bundle/config (Bundler::GenericSystemCallError)
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:122:in `rescue in filesystem_access'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:108:in `filesystem_access'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.2/lib/bundler/settings.rb:311:in `load_config'
```

I manually created the /usr/share/redmine/.bundle/config directory and made it belong to www-data:www-data with chmod 775.

However, /usr/share/redmine itself belongs to root:root and chmod 755.

Is this rather a passenger problem than a gems/bundler problem?

Apache VHost is configured with PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on.
PassengerDefaultUser is www-data.

EDIT: almost forgot to add that when I run `bundle install` there is no output whatsoever, not even any error message. It just returns to prompt immediately, as if nothing happened.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer instead of editing your question. You can mark your own answer as accepted after 24 hours (iirc).

Comment: @HolgerJust OK, I've done that and will mark my answer as accepted tomorrow. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bundle/config` is not a directory. I just deleted `.bundle` with `rm -rf .bundle` and created it again as root with `mkdir .bundle` and the installation is OK now.

Still don't understand why the `.bundle` directory was not automatically created by bundler but oh well.